# ¿Como puedo corregir este mensaje que se me genera la actualizar una tabla que contiene registros e imágenes en PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, update

he intentado actualizar la información de una tabla que contiene una imagenes al momento de generar la actualización me arroja el siguiente mensaje. Notice: Undefined index: img in C:\xampp\htdocs\Proyecto\Actualizarcont.php on line 15 junto con este Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in C:\xampp\htdocs\Proyecto\Actualizarcont.php on line 15, la verdad he intentado de varias maneras actualizar la imagenes pero no lo he logrado, si alguien me puede dar una guia o sugerirme otro tipo de edición. Gracias

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el codigo que he utilizado...

```
<?php

include_once("Conexion.php");


$objConexion = Conectarse();

$titulo = $_REQUEST ['titulo'];
$titulosec = $_REQUEST['titulosec'];
$descripcion = $_REQUEST ['descripcion'];
$img= $_REQUEST ['img'];
$id=$_REQUEST ['id'];

if (isset($_FILES['img'])) {
    $nombreImg=$_FILES['img']['name'];
    $ruta=$_FILES['img']['tmp_name'];
    $destino="../imagenes/".$nombreImg;

$selecionar = "SELECT ruta FROM tbl_contenido WHERE id = '$id'";
$resultado_seleccionar = mysqli_query($objConexion, $selecionar);

$img_db = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado_seleccionar);
$ruta_img_db = "../imagenes/" . $img_db['img'];

if(file_exists($ruta_img_db)){
    unlink($ruta_img_db);
}
if (!file_exists($destino)) {
    move_uploaded_file($ruta,$destino);
}

if ($_FILES['img']['name']) {
    $updatecont =" UPDATE tbl_contenido SET Titulo ='".$titulo."', Titulo_Sec = '".$titulosec."',
         Descripcion = '".$descripcion."', ruta = '".$destino."' WHERE id ='".$id."'";

    $resultado = $objConexion->query($updatecont) or die($objConexion->error);

    echo "<script>
alert('Actualizacion Exitosa');
window.location = 'Admin.php';
</script>";
}
} else {
    echo "<script>
alert('No se pudo actualizar el registro');
window.location = 'Admin.php';
</script>";
}
```

Comment: ¿Has intentado hacer un `print_r($_FILES);` para validar que exista el `$_FILES['img']`?..  No sé cómo estás mandando a llamar a la función, pero en algún lugar debe haber algo que llene dicha variable, por lo general un formulario multipart, con un input tipo file... por otro lado `$img_db['img']` no contiene el indice img ya que la consulta `SELECT ruta FROM tbl_contenido ...` está devolviendo ruta en vez de img..

Comment: Muchas gracias, efectivamente me hacía falta el multipart en el form, ya me esta editando la imagen.